# Unable to send whole file over TCP connection! (UNIX C)

Tags: c, sockets, unix

So I programmed a multi threaded web server, here is one function from the program. This function takes output file descriptor (`fd`), content type, pointer to data to be served (`*buf`) and size of the data (`numbytes`). It always gets stuck at 5775 bytes! I've tried using `write()` instead of `send()`, but no avail! I tried to send whole `buf` at a time, and even tried to transfer it in chunks, but `wget` shows that it gets stck at 5775 bytes! Here is the code:

```
int return_result(int fd, char *content_type, char *buf, int numbytes)
{
    char out_buf[BUF_SIZE], numb[6];
    int buf_len, total = 0, buf_size;
    long int i = 0;
    sprintf(numb, "%d", numbytes);
    strcpy(out_buf, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK \nContent-Type: ");
    strcat(out_buf, content_type);
    strcat(out_buf, "\nContent-Length: ");
    strcat(out_buf, numb);
    strcat(out_buf, "\nConnection: Close\n  \n");
    printf("\nSending HTTP Header\n %d bytes sent!",
           send(fd, out_buf, strlen(out_buf), 0));
    char *start = NULL, *str = NULL, *temp = NULL;
    start = buf;
    printf("\n Start Pointer Val = %ld", &start);
    while (start != NULL) {
        printf("\n While Loop");
        if (i + 2048 * sizeof(char) < numbytes) {
            printf("\n If 1");
            str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2048);
            memcpy(str, start, sizeof(char) * 2048);
            i = i + 2048 * sizeof(char);
            buf_size = send(fd, str, 2048, 0);
            free(str);
            printf("\n Sent %d bytes total : %d", buf_size, total =
                   total + buf_size);

            temp = start + sizeof(char) * 2048;
            start = temp;

        } else {

            i = numbytes - i * sizeof(char);
            if (i > 0) {
                printf("\n If 2");
                printf("\n Value of i %d", i);
                str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * i);
                memcpy(str, start, sizeof(char) * i);
                printf("Total bytes finally sent:%d", total =
                       total + send(fd, str, i, 0));
                if (total == numbytes) {
                    printf("\nTransfer Complete!");
                }
                free(str);

            }
            start = NULL;
        }
    }
    printf("out of loop!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you actually getting the "Total bytes finally sent:.." message matching what you expect? If so it may be a buffering/flushing issue.

Comment: Yes, infact I'm send()ing all the bytes from server side, but wget receives only 5775!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (`printf()` statements omitted for clarity):

```
int send_buf(in fd, void *buf, int numbytes)
{
    char *start = (char*) buf;
    while (numbytes > 0)
    {
        int sent = send(fd, start, numbytes, 0);
        if (sent <= 0)
        {
            if ((sent == -1) && (errno == EAGAIN))
            {
                fd_set wfds;
                FD_ZERO(&wfds);
                FD_SET(fd, &wfds);
                if (select(fd + 1, NULL, &wfds, NULL, NULL) == 1)
                    continue;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        start += sent;
        numbytes -= sent;
    }

    return 0;
}

int return_result(int fd, char *content_type, void *buf, int numbytes) 
{ 
    char out_buf[BUF_SIZE], 

    int len = sprintf(out_buf,
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        "Content-Type: %s\r\n"
        "Content-Length: %d\r\n"
        "Connection: Close\r\n"
        "\r\n",
        content_type,
        numb); 

    if (send_buf(fd, out_buf, len) != 0)
        return -1;

    if (send_buf(fd, buf, numbytes) != 0)
        return -1;

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! What was the problem with my solution?

Comment: When you were sending a particular block of data, whether it was your formatted HTTP headers or a chunk of the input data buffer, you were calling `send()` only once per block. That is not guaranteed to send the entire block in one go.  In fact, it very likely won't in many cases. `send()` returns how many bytes were actually accepted. You have to keep calling `send()` until the enire block has been sen. In my example, I do exactly that, with an extra call to `select()` for sockets operating in non-blocking mode (you did not say what you are using).

Comment: Another bug in your code was this line: `temp = start + sizeof(char) * 2048;`. That should have been this instead: `temp = start + (buf_size * sizeof(char));`, which can be simplified to this: `temp = start + buf_size;` using pointer arithmetic, which can then be further simplified to this: `start += buf_size;` like I use in my code.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response! I totally get it now!

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest replacing your code with the following `writen()` function from [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 2nd edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programming_in_the_Unix_Environment):

```
ssize_t             /* Write "n" bytes to a descriptor  */
writen(int fd, const void *ptr, size_t n)
{
        size_t          nleft;
        ssize_t         nwritten;

        nleft = n;
        while (nleft > 0) {
                if ((nwritten = write(fd, ptr, nleft)) < 0) {
                        if (nleft == n)
                                return(-1); /* error, return -1 */
                        else
                                break;      /* error, return amount written so far */
                } else if (nwritten == 0) {
                        break;
                }
                nleft -= nwritten;
                ptr   += nwritten;
        }
        return(n - nleft);      /* return >= 0 */
}
```

This code is already debugged and known working, and further allows `write(2)` to write `PIPE_BUF` bytes at a go for better speed when things are working well.

`send(2)` *should* block if it cannot send all the data you have requested, though. I think more interesting would be debugging the version with plain `send(2)` without any of the surrounding efforts to break things into blocks.

Better than both `write(2)` and `send(2)` would be `sendfile(2)` -- open the file, pass the descriptor and socket to `sendfile(2)`, and let the kernel handle it all for you, using zero-copy mechanisms if possible.

One last point: [HTTP uses CRLF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Request_message), not plain carriage returns. Each `\n` should be replaced with `\r\n`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs! I added your code, but wget still gets stuck on 5775 bytes! I ssh'ed into different machines, and turns out I get same problem everywhere! Any thoughts?